# Problema com jQuery de abrir/fechar divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho um jQuery que fiz para abrir e fechar uma div ao clicar na pergunta correspondente. O problema é que somente a primeira div está abrindo\fechando, mesmo eu clicando na 3ª ou 5ª pergunta.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/1sozc3rL/

jQuery:

```
var SC = jQuery.noConflict();

SC(document).ready(function() {
    SC('.FAQ-conteudo').hide();
    SC('.FAQ-fecha').hide();
    SC('.FAQ-pergunta').removeClass('FAQ-atual');
    SC('.FAQ-pergunta').click(function(){
        var i = SC(this).index();
        var faqTemClasse = SC('.FAQ-pergunta:eq('+i+')').hasClass('FAQ-atual');
        if (faqTemClasse) {
            SC('.FAQ-pergunta:eq('+i+')').removeClass('FAQ-atual');
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo:eq('+i+')').fadeOut(300);
            SC('.FAQ-fecha:eq('+i+')').hide();
            SC('.FAQ-abre:eq('+i+')').show();
        } else {
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo').fadeOut(300);
            SC('.FAQ-pergunta:eq('+i+')').addClass('FAQ-atual');
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo:eq('+i+')').fadeIn(300);
            SC('.FAQ-fecha:eq('+i+')').show();
            SC('.FAQ-abre:eq('+i+')').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Fiz mais uns testes e realmente ele está pegando apenas o index 0, por isso está abrindo\fechando somente a primeira div de conteúdo.

O `.index()` não pega a ordem de elementos dentro de todo o arquivo, independendo do lugar?

Comment: Como são várias DIVs, acho que você poderia mostrar/esconder setando IDs em cada uma delas, e não por classe como você está fazendo. Você teria mais controle das ações de cada DIV.

Comment: Mas eu teria que criar um script jQuery para cada evento de cada div, certo? Queria algo padrão :\

Comment: Tem razão. Eu usei o [_collapse_](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso, como tem várias perguntas com marcação igual só mudando o conteúdo, recomendo usar o contexto do seletor em vez de usar o índice.

O padrão que se repete para cada pergunta é:

```
<div class="FAQ-box cf">
    <a class="fx left FAQ-pergunta">Titulo</a>
    <img src="..." class="middle FAQ-abre right" />
    <img src="..." class="middle FAQ-fecha right" />
    <div class="clear FAQ-conteudo">
        texto e mais texto
    </div>
</div>
```

Você faz bind de `click` no `.FAQ-pergunta`, podemos escolher o contexto dos seletores como o pai dele, onde fazendo "transversal" conseguimos todos os elementos necessários no script.

O uso do contexto se faz da seguinte forma:

```
$('.seletor', contexto).oqueseja();
```

Com isso, qualquer elemento que faça "matching" desse seletor a partir da sub-árvore do contexto será incluído. Os demais serão ignorados.

O seletor padrão começa a busca pelo do `document`. Usando o contexto ele começa a busca pelo elemento contexto.

No seu script ficará:

```
var SC = jQuery.noConflict();

SC(document).ready(function() {
    SC('.FAQ-conteudo').hide();
    SC('.FAQ-fecha').hide();
    SC('.FAQ-pergunta').removeClass('FAQ-atual');
    SC('.FAQ-pergunta').click(function(){
        var $this = SC(this);
        var $pai = $this.parent(); // O pai, que engloba tudo que voce usa nesse script será o contexto!
        var faqTemClasse = SC('.FAQ-pergunta', $pai).hasClass('FAQ-atual');

        if (faqTemClasse) {
            SC('.FAQ-pergunta', $pai).removeClass('FAQ-atual');
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo', $pai).fadeOut(300);
            SC('.FAQ-fecha', $pai).hide();
            SC('.FAQ-abre', $pai).show();
        } else {
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo', $pai).fadeOut(300);
            SC('.FAQ-pergunta', $pai).addClass('FAQ-atual');
            SC('.FAQ-conteudo', $pai).fadeIn(300);
            SC('.FAQ-fecha', $pai).show();
            SC('.FAQ-abre', $pai).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sozc3rL/1/).

Mais informações dê uma olhada no parágrafo **Selector Context** na [documentação do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

Comment: Poxa, eu estava justamente tentando adicionar um "pai" ao código e não estava conseguindo. Muito obrigado! :D Funcionou como eu queria!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o toggle no elemento clicado e o not para operar com os outros, assim:

**Jquery:**

```
var SC = jQuery.noConflict();

SC(document).ready(function() {
    SC('.FAQ-conteudo, .FAQ-fecha').hide(); // oculta todos os .FAQ-conteúdo e .FAQ-fecha
    SC('.FAQ-pergunta').click(function(){
        SC('.FAQ-pergunta').not(this).removeClass('FAQ-atual'); // remove a classe FAQ-atual de todas as perguntas, exceto da pergunta clicada
        SC('.FAQ-conteudo').not(SC(this).siblings('.FAQ-conteudo')).slideUp(300); // oculta todos os .FAQ-conteúdo abertos, exceto o irmão da pergunta clicada
        SC('.FAQ-fecha').not(SC(this).siblings('.FAQ-fecha')).hide(); // oculta todos os .FAQ-fecha, exceto o irmão da pergunta clicada
        SC('.FAQ-abre').not(SC(this).siblings('.FAQ-abre')).show(); // mostra todos os .FAQ-abre, exceto o irmão da pergunta clicada
        SC(this).toggleClass('FAQ-atual').siblings('.FAQ-conteudo').slideToggle(300).siblings('.FAQ-fecha, .FAQ-abre').toggle(); // inverte a classe FAQ-atual na pergunta clicada . inverte o slide no .FAQ-conteúdo irmão da pergunta clicada . inverte a exibição em .FAQ-fecha e .FAQ-abre, irmãos da pergunta clicada
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/x31xn83r/)

---

Algumas das funções do jquery tem sua versão `toggle`, que atua invertendo o status atual, então temos:

`toggleClass(classe)` se a classe esta adicionada ele remove, e se não está, ele adiciona.

`slideToggle` se esta visível ele oculta com slide, se esta oculto ele exibe com slide.

`toggle` se esta visível ele oculta, se esta oculto ele exibe.

---

A função `.not(elemento)` retira da seleção os elementos nela listados.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem seu código, mas funcionou. Vou estudar esses novos comandos. Obrigado.

Comment: @Ricardo Editei a resposta e comentei cada linha...

Comment: @Ricardo Havia um pequeno bug, `addClass('FAQ-atual')` deveria ser `toggleClass('FAQ-atual')`, e também `SC('.FAQ-pergunta').removeClass('FAQ-atual');` deveria ser: `SC('.FAQ-pergunta').not(this).removeClass('FAQ-atual');`, corrigi na resposta e no jsfiddle.

Comment: @Ricardo Para esse tipo de apresentação eu acho que o efeito slide fica melhor que o fade, veja o funcionamento no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/x31xn83r/).

Comment: Verdade. Fica esteticamente melhor. Obrigado :D